# Visual Studio 2015 - Update 1 - Debugger only runs once then I have to rebuild all

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug-symbols

Just wondering if anyone might have encountered and fixed the issue I'm experiencing. I've migrated all my code bases to from a windows 8 machine to window 10 and now the debugger only seems to hook in properly once when I run an MVC project. Then I get the usual Symbols Not Loaded on any break points and have to rebuild the entire solution to get the debugger working again.

I've tried clearing out .suo file, updating all Nu Get packages but nothing seems to make any difference and it's happening in all my projects/solutions.

Comment: update to vs2015 update 2 and try again

Comment: @magicandre1981 ok will do - I didn't realise it was out

Comment: This does seem to have resolved the issue.

Comment: nice to hear this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During Build conference, Microsoft released the Update 2 for Visual Studio 2015, which includes [several fixes](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update2-vs). [Download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129) and install the Update 2 ad look if it fixes your issue.